# Suspicious directory ".MySecurityData" in internal storage

Tags: security, samsung-galaxy-note

I have a Galaxy Note (N7000) device running stock Android 4.1.2. I was browsing the internal storage and noticed a directory named ".MySecurityData", which contains one single directory "dont_remove", which contains multiple directories whose name consists of hexadecimal characters of length 32 (presumably MD5 hashes). All those 3rd level directories contain three directories - ".image", ".thumb", and ".video". A search through `find` command reveals that all the directories are empty containing no files.

Fact that the parent directory is hidden, directories have suspicious and obfuscated names, and a web search returns no results for ".MySecurityData" has raised concerns of some malicious activity.

Can anyone identify the application that may have created these directories? I'm a paranoid person and usually shy away from installing apps, and double check the ones that I'm installing.

There is also a SQLite3 file inside "dont_remove" (name is again in hexadecimal characters of length 15). A SQLite3 `.dump` on this file results in following:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES('en_GB');
CREATE TABLE medias (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,album TEXT, from_path TEXT, dest_path TEXT,thumb_path TEXT,file_name TEXT,file_type TEXT,file_ext TEXT,timestamp LONG,rotation INTEGER DEFAULT 0);
COMMIT
```

**UPDATE**:

After a `grep` through dumpstate logs in `/data/log`, I noticed that the SQLite3 file was being accessed by [`com.domobile.applock`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock). I've emailed the developer asking for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a `grep` through dumpstate logs in `/data/log`, I noticed that the SQLite3 file was being accessed by [`com.domobile.applock`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ls` command, you can find out the owner (and group) of those directories. Following this with a `ls` on `/data`, and watching out for the same ownership, you should find only one hit, reveaing the package name of the corresponding app – which you then can use on the Google Play website to find the matching app (by placing the found package name after the `id=` part of the URL).

As access to the `/data` directory is restricted, the above commands must be executed with root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

AppLock is a legitimate app, considering that you opted to install it. It allows the device owner to assign a password to any app, settings area, or even Google Play thereby making it possible (for example) to lend the device to a young child without having to worry about the youth accessing those apps, settings or store. The app works as defined. I would therefore not consider the directories as suspicious, if they indeed are owned by AppLock as a previous post clarified.